# Why my parameter isn't callable for Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

so i'm trying to learn about classes in python but for some reason i can't get Wiek function working.

i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pythonProject/MEDIUM.py", line 36, in <module>
    fafik.Wiek()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

```
class Pies(Ssaki):
    def __init__(self, LiczbaKonczynPsa, ImiePsa, WiekPsa):
        self.LiczbaKonczyn = LiczbaKonczynPsa
        self.Wiek = WiekPsa
        self.Imie = ImiePsa

    def Przedstaw(self):
        print('Ten pies wabi się: ', self.Imie)
    def Konczyny(self):
        print('Ten pies posiada ', self.LiczbaKonczyn, 'kończyny')
    def Wiek(self):
        print('Wiek psa wynosi 6')

fafik = Pies(4, 'BOBO', WiekPsa=3)
fafik.Przedstaw()
fafik.Konczyny()
fafik.Wiek()
```

I'm sorry for asking maybe so stupid question but i truly can't fin solution to my problem.

Comment: What do you want `Wiek` to be? You currently have it as a method in the class, but overwrite it at runtime with the `WiekPsa` parameter.

Comment: Note that your code is confusing to read for Python programmers, because names starting with a capital letter usually indicate classes, not methods or method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you have both a class attribute named `Wiek`, which in your example is the int `3`, *and* a method called `Wiek()`, which you try to call on the last line of your example. Since `self.Wiek` has already been defined as `3`, calling `fafik.Wiek()` is the equivalent of calling `fafik.3()`, which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. i was looking at this for 15 min and couldnt't figure out something so obvious

Answer (score 0):

```
def Wiek(self):
        print('Wiek psa wynosi 6')
self.Wiek = WiekPsa
```

You have a parameter called Wiek, but also a method called Wiek
When you call `fafik.Wiek()` python tries to call your parameter Wiek which is an int, and tries to call it as a function which is not possible since it's a int

In any case, don't give a parameter and a function the same name; except for very precise case (getters)

Just rename either the variable Wiek, or the function to a new name and it will work

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that your class has two items having the same name.

1. An attribute, of type 'int'.
2. A method.

When you call your function here `fafik.Wiek()`it understands that you're trying to call the integer attribute as a method.
Just change the name of your function.